# CodeIgniter/Ajax - Redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, redirect

I have a simple log-in form with CodeIgniter and jQuery. I have a couple of questions considering redirects and best practices. Here's my ajax call code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnLogin").click(function(e)    {
        $("p.error").hide();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $(".loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/login/go",
            data: ({email: email, password: password}),
            success: function(data){
                $(".loader").hide();
                if(!data['status'])
                {
                    $("p.error").html(data['error']);
                    $("p.error").slideDown("fast");
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location = "site/index";
                }
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

As you can see, I return true or false from my controller (in data['status']) and move forward from that. However, I'm not sure if the `window.location = ""` is the right way to do this. Security-wise, is it okay to put that URL there? 
People cannot access site/index without having logged in first. Logging in correctly sets a CI-session and site/index checks for that. If someone is not logged in, they get redirected to the login page. I just feel a bit weird having that URL in my ajax call, haha :(

I tried to solve this by just putting `redirect("site/index")` in my controller after setting the session. Some code so this makes sense:

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // validation failed, returns false
    }
    else
    { 
                    // successful
                    // sets session and then i tried doing:
                    redirect("site/index");
    }
```

However, this doesn't work. I don't really understand why it doesn't work, so if someone could explain that I'd be very grateful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the **first part** of your question:
You can always put `data['my_redirect']='site/index'` in controller and return that with `data['status']`, so your site structure wont be 'exposed' for others to view.
As for the **second part**:
Its not working because you have an Ajax request, and you cant make redirect on server before you return data to JavaScript that made that request.

Comment: -@trix, can you explain the second part more? what data needs to be returned in order to change the URL?

Comment: please read cabaret's comment on d2burke's answer (if that's what you are referring to)

Answer (score 2):

cabaret - not sure if you're still having this issue, but as I was searching for it I found this and then eventually found a suitable solution, so i figured i'd post the link to what i did.  i posted the code and explanation on the CI forums:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/65486/

hope that helps

Comment: I'll read through the thread and see if I can perhaps update my own solution a bit to improve it. Since I'm working with AJAX, I just return a $feedback array from my controller with has a key called 'redirect'. The content of this key is where the redirect should go. In my AJAX success function, I then do `window.location = data['redirect']`; this seems to work fine. Thanks for getting to this and posting the link!